# Экс чемпион мира по шахматам и экс-чемпион

Tags: орфография

1.экс чемпион мира по шахматам, экс министр обороны, экс президент России. 
2.экс-чемпион, экс-министр, экс-президент

в первом случае - раздельно

во втором - через дефис?

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: экс министр обороны, экс президент России; .экс-чемпион, экс-министр, экс-президент

> Недопустимо слитное или дефисное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть содержит пробел, т. е. представляет собой сочетание слов. В этих случаях слитные или дефисные написания, рекомендуемые основными правилами, должны заменяться раздельными. Например, следует писать: ***лже доктор наук, экс Советский Союз.***

[См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006. § 153](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80)

Comment: Очень плохо выглядит раздельная форма написания: получается полная форма прилагательного без русского окончания. Я бы исключил из норм такой речевой вариант, поскольку его легко обойти применением русских слов "бывший" и "мнимый" :) , даже в устной форме применение "экс-" и "лже-" к составным понятиям воспринимается как просторечие. Как компромисс (поскольку просторечия тоже как-то записывают), готов принять раздельное написание с дефисом.